# Inserting the same value into the column

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a code for saving coordinates of every point of polyline to Access database. Table where I save these coordinates consist of 6 columns: ID, ENT_ID, ORDER_NUM, X, Y, Z. Every point has a ORDER_NUM. When I create polyline with 5 points ORDER_NUM stars with 0 to 4( it's just counter for point). But I need SQL that fills ENT_ID with same values within one polyline. For example I have polyline with 5 points and for every point ENT_ID should be the same. When I draw a new polyline ENT_ID should be incremented by 1 and all over again. Any suggestions?

```
Public Shared Sub SavePolyLine(Byval point As Point3d, ByVal username As String, ByVal geomId As Handle, ByVal pointIndex As Integer)
    Dim groupid as Integer
    Dim ObjectsInGroup As List(Of Handle) = New List(Of Handle)
    Dim sqlInsertIntoPline As String = "INSERT INTO Polyline (ENT_ID) VALUES (pENT_ID)"
    Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT GROUP_ID from Groups"
    Dim sqlQryEnt As String = "INSERT INTO EntityParams (Geom_type, CREATED_BY, UPDATED_BY) VALUES (pGeom_type,pCreated,pUpdated)"
    Dim sqlQryPolyline As String = "INSERT INTO Polylinepoints (ENT_ID, ORDER_NUM, X, Y, Z) VALUES (pENT_ID, pORDER_NUM , pX, pY, pZ)"
    Dim myconnection As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlSelect, myconnection)


    Using myconnection
        myconnection.Open()
        Using cmd
            Using cmd
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pGroup_name",groupName)
                If cmd.ExecuteScalar IsNot Nothing Then
                    groupId = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                End If
            End Using


    End Using


        cmd.CommandText = sqlQryEnt
        cmd.Connection = myconnection
        Using cmd
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pGeom_type", "Polyline")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCreated", username)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUpdated", username)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = "WHICH SQL???"
            EntId = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        End Using

         cmd.CommandText = sqlInsertIntoPline
        cmd.Connection = myconnection
        Using cmd
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pENT_ID", EntId)  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        cmd.CommandText = sqlQryPolyline
        cmd.Connection = myconnection
        Using cmd
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pENT_ID", EntId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pORDER_NUM", pointIndex)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pX", point.X)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pY", point.Y)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pZ", point.Z)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

    myconnection.Close()
    If DictAutoCadIdToDbId.ContainsKey(geomId.value) Then
    ObjectsInGroup.Add(GeomId)
    AddToGroup(groupName,GeomId)
      Else
            DictAutoCadIdToDbId.Add(GeomId.Value(), EntId)
        End If

    RightPal.RefreshTree()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in an array of Points for your polyline then you can loop through them incrementing the index and inserting a record with each loop. I guessed that you have your own Structure/Class for Point so I added one just so my code would compile.

```
Private Sub EnterPolyline(EntId As Integer, myPoints() As Point)
        Dim myconnection As New OleDbConnection("Connection String")
        Dim sqlQryPolyline As String = "INSERT INTO Polylinepoints (ENT_ID, ORDER_NUM, X, Y, Z) VALUES (pENT_ID, pORDER_NUM , pX, pY, pZ)"

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQryPolyline, myconnection)
            Dim pointIndex As Integer = 0
            For Each aPoint In myPoints
                Dim poinIndex As Integer = 0
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pENT_ID", EntId)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pORDER_NUM", pointIndex)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pX", aPoint.X)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pY", aPoint.y)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pZ", aPoint.Z)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                pointIndex += 1
            Next
        End Using
End Sub
Public Structure Point
        Public X As Integer
        Public y As Integer
        Public Z As Integer
End Structure
```